# Is av_fast_realloc faster than av_realloc?

Tags: ffmpeg

Should I use it instead? Looks like it's just more compact.

https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__mem__funcs.html

Comment: "Reallocate the given buffer if it is not large enough, otherwise do nothing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the whole function from latest version, it actually calls `av_realloc` but first checks if the supplied buffer is large enough as it says in the documentation, if it is then it doesn't do `av_realloc`, actually it doesn't do anything other then returning same buffer in this case. Hope that helps.

```
void *av_fast_realloc(void *ptr, unsigned int *size, size_t min_size)
{
    if (min_size <= *size)
        return ptr;

    if (min_size > max_alloc_size - 32) {
        *size = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    min_size = FFMIN(max_alloc_size - 32, FFMAX(min_size + min_size / 16 + 32, min_size));

    ptr = av_realloc(ptr, min_size);
    /* we could set this to the unmodified min_size but this is safer
     * if the user lost the ptr and uses NULL now
     */
    if (!ptr)
        min_size = 0;

    *size = min_size;

    return ptr;
}
```